# replace multibyte utf8 character in php

Tags: php, utf-8, replace, multibyte

I am trying to preg_replace the multibytecharacter for euro in UTF (shown as â¬ in my html) to a "$" and the * for an "@"

```
$orig = "2 **** reviews  â¬ 19,99 price";
$orig = mb_ereg_replace(mb_convert_encoding('&#x20ac;', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES'), "$", $orig);
$orig = preg_replace("/[\$\;\?\!\{\}\(\)\[\]\/\*\>\<]/", "@", $orig);
$a = htmlentities($orig);
$b = html_entity_decode($a);
```

The "*" are being replaced but not the "â¬" .......

Also tried to replace it with

```
$orig = preg_replace("/[\xe2\x82\xac]/", "$", $orig);
```

Doesn't convert either....

Another plan which didnt work:

```
$orig= mb_ereg_replace(mb_convert_encoding('&#x20ac;', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES'), "$", $orig);
```

Brrr someone knows how to get rid of this utf8 euro character:

```
echo html_entity_decode('&euro;');
```

(driving me nuts)

Comment: Wouldn't str_replace(html_entity_decode('&euro;'), '$', $source) work?

Comment: from `$orig = str_replace(html_entity_decode('&euro;'), '$', $orig);` i get an error: "syntax error, unexpected ','"

Comment: Your syntax error has to be from somwhere else, i just asted the code on my server and it works fine, there are no syntax error... You sure you copied the stuff as is?

Comment: Lol, i looked at this so long that i missed completely it was another line.... So it works ! One thing; why can't i get this to work with preg_replace.. ? Thanks al lot btw !

Comment: I don't know, i only do basic regexp, maybe someone else can help you on that part

Answer (score 4):

This could be caused by two reasons:

1. The actual source text is UTF8 encoded, but your PHP code not.
   You can solve this by just using this line and save your file UTF8 encoded (try using notepad++).

   str_replace('€', '$', $source);
2. The source text is corrupted: multibyte characters are converted to latin1 (wrong database charset?). You can try to convert them back to latin1:

   str_replace('€', '$', utf8_decode($source))

Answer (score 0):

Pasting my comment here as an answer so you can mark it!

Wouldn't

```
str_replace(html_entity_decode('&euro;'), '$', $source)
```

work?

Answer (score 0):

In your `$orig` string you do not have euro sign.
When I run this php file:

```
<?php
$orig = "â¬";
for($i=0; $i<strlen($orig); $i++)
    echo '0x' . dechex(ord($orig{$i})) . ' ';
?>
```

If saved as utf-8 I get: `0xc3 0xa2 0xc2 0xac`

If saved as latin-1 I get: `0xe2 0xac`

In any case it is not € sign which is:`0xE2 0x82 0xAC` or unicode `\u20AC` ( http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm ).
`0x82` is missing!!!!!

Run this program above, see what do you get and use this hex values to get rid of `â¬`.

For real `€` sign this works:

```
<?php
    $orig = html_entity_decode('&euro;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    $dest = preg_replace('~\x{20ac}~u', '$', $orig);

    echo "($orig) ($dest)";
?>
```

BTW if UTF-8 file containing € is displayed as latin-1 you should get:
`â‚¬` and not `â¬` as in your example.

So in fact, you have problems with encoding and conversion between encodings. If you try to save `â‚¬` in latin1 middle character will be lost (for example my Komodo will alert me and then replace `‚` with `?`). In other words, you somehow damaged your € sign - and then you tried to replace it as it was complete. :D